# DateBox Calender is coming behinde Vertical Panel Popup

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I have a search icon, when i click on that, a search popup will opens(which is actually a vertical panel). In this Date textboxes are there. when i am clicking on a Data textbox. Its coming, but its behind the Vertical Panel popup.

My question is, when datebox is clicked, Calender should come front. What i have to do for that.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in Advance,
Saritha.

Comment: Atleast if there is a way to set the position of the Datepicker, then that will be temporarly solves my problem..can anyone please reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the CSS z-index property for the calendar to a higher value than the popup's z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Using z-index didn't work for me. I removed all z-index values from style sheets instead, and so far it worked.

Hope it can be of use for you.

G.